# How to disable the loading circle of a browser ( near favicon )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to disable the loading bar of the browser i.e above the address bar as show here :

[image]

I have seen on many websites such as [Rededition](https://rededition.com/en/) in which when we click on a hyperlink the browser loading circle near favicon is not shown

Comment: You can't...that's a browser object not a HTML/CSS one. Your linked page, I think, is not loading actual new pages

Answer (score 1):

The page your are referring to isn't loading a new page when a link is clicked, all the necessary pages have already been pre-loaded in one html file. If you notice in the url bar you don't see the file extension being loaded.

Comment: yes pages are not loaded but the site browses within folders

Comment: how?? , i also want to make a website like this

Comment: for information, the website https://rededition.com/en is built on wordpress that may have a plugin for this type of working i also want to know about that plugin if it's possible